# Using Matlab with an Android and Windows phone app

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, matlab, signal-processing

I am fairly new to mobile development platform. I was wondering if I could use a Matlab script in an Android and Windows phone app. Or are there some other image processing libraries available !

---

Comment: Do you mean that you are looking for a way to install Matlab on your phone ?  Or are you looking for something else to run your Matlab scripts on your phone ?  As for other image processing libraries, let Google be your friend, SO isn't a very good replacement for a general-purpose search engine; it's not intended to be.

Comment: I mean I need to process an image in my app, for which I have a matlab script. Can I use it in my Windows phone ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an official **Matlab mobile** application available for iOS: http://www.mathworks.de/mobile/

For android, there is **Matlab Connect**, which, however, seems not to be supported by Mathworks: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chschmid.mlconnectfree&hl=en

A Matlab clone running on Android is **Addi**: http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=3908

Comment: What about the Windows platform ?

Comment: @CSSS: I am not aware of an application for the Windows platform (otherwise I would have pointed to it in my answer).